# laravel form data not being saved to database

Tags: php, database, laravel-5, eloquent

laravel is giving me a strange error, few moments ago, datas were being sent to the database, now its not. When I do `dd(Input:all())` inside my controller, I get all the values submitted from the form, here is the snaphshot of it.
[image]

and here is my function where I am trying to insert data to the database

```
$product = new Products;

$product->user_id           = Auth::user()->id;
$product->category_id       = $idOfCategory;
$product->subcategory_id    = $idOfSubCategory;
$product->title             = Input::get('title');
$product->product_slug      = str_slug(Input::get('title'));
$product->description       = Input::get('description');
$product->runtime           = Input::get('runtime');
$product->adtype            = Input::get('adtype');
$product->location          = Input::get('location');
$product->price             = Input::get('price');
$product->image1            = $fileName1;
$product->image2            = $fileName2;
$product->image3            = $fileName3;
$product->negotiable        = Input::get('negotiable');
$product->product_condition = Input::get('product_condition');
$product->usedfor           = Input::get('usedfor');
$product->detailurl         = Input::get('detailurl');
$product->status            = 'available';

$product->save();
```

and this is my product model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Products extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'products';

}
```

what might be the problem?

Comment: It  is possible that some fields are not passing validation. Make sure that $product->save() == True

Comment: So where is the code to update the database? Did you think it happened by magic?

Comment: @RiggsFolly if the data has to get saved to database, it would have saved with this code, its not being saved.. my other functions with similar codes are running properly..

Comment: @AlexChorry found it. one of the field was not passing validation, thanks

Comment: @Sid Can you post your solution as an answer (+ accept it) - just so others know it's resolved and don't have to hunt through comments to figure it out? :)